# Can't access environment variables in Flutter project when building in Vercel

Tags: flutter, environment-variables, vercel

I want to access an environment variable in a Flutter Web project by using:
`String.fromEnvironment('API_KEY')`

Everything works fine in an local "VisualStudio Code" environment using the .vscode>launch.json file to deploy the variable 'API_KEY'.

On a Vercel environment I try to deploy the environment variable by using the Vercel Settings:
[Vercel Environment Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uetgT.png)

But now `String.fromEnvironment('API_KEY')` returns an empty string.

Has anyone experienced similar problems with Flutter on Vercel?

I also double check that the env variable in Vercel is deployed in all three environments (Production, Preview, Environment).

Comment: Using `dotenv` package also doesn't work. Check similar issues:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/77954467/10482516 and
https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/3879#discussion-5582334

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Don't use the environment variables in the Vercel Settings as it does not work (well I haven't found a way to make it work).

Instead, you need to pass your API_KEY using **--dart-define** when building your app. To do this, modify your build command in your project settings like this:

```
flutter/bin/flutter build web --release --dart-define=API_KEY=yourkeyhere
```

Now, deploy your app again (if it has already been deployed) and now you can access your environment variables like your API_KEY. However, note that this build command only has a maximum length of 256 characters.

Comment: It works but it raise security concern if you store secret information. Your key is publicly accessible in the main. In my case, OpenAI detect it and disable my api key.

Comment: I have added my env variables in vercel settings. Since i don't wanna put keys directly in the build command, I try to build web using this command flutter/bin/flutter build web --release --dart-define-from-file=.env, I get exited with 1. NEED HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

If using the Vercel CLI, I think you need to run `vercel pull` before `vercel build` to ensure the build has access to the environment variables. Here's some more info on that command: https://vercel.com/docs/cli/pull