# How to use vercel Environment Variables in flutter web app

Tags: flutter, dart, environment-variables, vercel

I want to use the variables defined in vercel dasboard in "Environment variables" in my flutter web app.

I have .env file in my local machine but havent made public in my git repository for obvious reasons.

How to use use it if deploying it in vercel.

dotenv pub package dont work or not working in my case.

dotenv is not working for local environment also and showing the below error.
[image]

this is my pubspec

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.5 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  get: ^4.6.6
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.6.0
  http: 1.1.2
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.1.0
  

dev_dependencies:

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

assets:
  - .env
```

and I've tried putting env file in both root folder as well as web folder but nothing works.

and I've tried putting env file in both root folder as well as web folder but nothing works.

**I dont want to use --dart-define to define my api keys.**

I just want ENV Variables declared in vercel dashboard to work with my flutter web app

Comment: If you think how a web application works, it loads its code from the server in the browser. It doesn't have access to files on the local machine, but can fetch things from the server it was launched from (other other servers with the correct CORS settings). So, if you want to load settings files (or other assets) your webapp gets them from the server. You are concerned about the safety of your env file - not in git. You cannot therefore host it as an asset or the browser user will be able to view it in developer tools of the browser. Consider baking the settings into the compiled app.

Comment: If you don't mind the env file being fetched from the server, you should be able to continue with flutter_dotenv, but you need to make sure that the env file is in the correct place in your flutter assets folder (and pubspec). If you do a flutter build web, check that it does get copied to the build/web/assets folder

Comment: @RichardHeap No I cant add files into assets folder as it will be accessible to any user from browser window and Vercel takes code from git and then it compiles it,and my code is in Public Repo so I cant push my env to git. and flutter_dotenv doesnt support ".env" naming in flutter web

Comment: See comments above - basically you cannot expect to use an env file in any web application.

Comment: @RichardHeap I have added my env variables in vercel settings but when I try to build web using this command `flutter/bin/flutter build web --release --dart-define-from-file=.env`, I get `exited with 1` error